# Visual Studio for Mac not running with breakpoints

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-mac

I've created a Blazor WASM app in Visual Studio for Mac. I've created some breakpoints however when running in debug mode, none of the breakpoints get hit. Any suggestions as to why this may be and how to resolve it?

When not running:

[image]

When running:

[image]

I've attempted to uninstall and reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

If you added any scripts to your index.html file try removing the crossorigin="anonymous" attribute (if present).  I have a major Blazor WASM solution that recently stopped debugging with the latest VS 2022 Mac updates.  I explored everything.  I could create a new Blazor WASM project and debug it fine but my project simply would not debug.  I methodically added to my new project until debugging broke.  What caused it?  This line in my index.html file (using [] brackets only so it shows here):

[script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script]

I removed the crossorigin attribute and debugging worked again.  I've had that script in my index.html file for two years.  Only now did it break debugging.  Even more puzzling is that my jquery script can have the crossorigin attribute without breaking debugging.  The bootstrap and popper scripts break it.

I don't know if this is your issue but give it a look. I submitted a report to MS but have not heard back from them.  It's easy to reproduce.  Just create a new Blazor WASM project using the standard template and add the bootstrap script above with the crossorigin attribute.  It immediately breaks debugging.  It never did before.  I use VS 2022 for Mac.  Don't know if Windows has this issue but Mac does.  It's a very obscure bug.  Hopefully I can save someone else the hours it took me to track this down.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was using Firefox.

"Visual Studio 17.5 on Windows also seems to have the same behaviour where breakpoints are not hit when debugging a Blazor Web Assembly project with Firefox. Using Chrome and Edge work as expected."